# flat morphisms of rings

Tags: ring-theory, flatness

Let $A \to B \to C$ be morphisms of rings (commutative with 1). 
Suppose $A \to C$ is flat.

> Is $B \to C$ flat?

My attempt: let $1 \to M \to N$ be an exact sequence of $B$-modules. Tensor this by $\otimes_B C$: we get an exact sequence of $C$-modules 
$$1 \to K \to M \otimes_B C \to N \otimes_B C (*),$$ where $K$ is the obvious kernel. My aim is to show that $K = 1$. 
But since we have a morphism $\phi: A \to B$,  $1 \to M \to N$ is also an exact sequence of $A$-modules in a natural way (the action $A \times M$ is given by $(a, m) \mapsto \phi(a) \cdot m$). So let's tensor $1 \to M \to N$ with $\otimes_A C$; by flatness of $A \to C$, we have the exact sequence 
$$1 \to M \otimes_A C \to N \otimes_A C (**).$$ I want to claim that the sequences $(*)$ and $(**)$ are the same, thus implying that $K = 1$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You'll be more successful if instead you try to show that $B\to C$ *doesn't* have to be flat.  To find a counterexample, you might think about cases where $A=C$ and $A\to C$ is the identity map.